# How to check whether Xcode downloaded all profiles?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have Xcode version 8.3.2 (8E2002). I want to update provisioning profiles. Let's say I want to add new devices. I used to create an archive manually using fastlane. How can I check if all new devices start the new archive successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check what provisioning profiles have been downloaded, you can go to the provisioning profile directory on your Mac (`~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`) In there will be the downloaded profiles.  You can open the .mobileprovision files in TextEdit and find the `<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>` entry.  There you will find the list of UDIDs for the devices that are in the provisioning profile.

To update your provisioning profiles, you should be able to go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details and click the "Download All Profiles" button.

If you are having problems with the automatic profile management in Xcode, you can always [do it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117905/3708242).